# Array fill in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have this problem with a lot of arrays in my program, and I can't understand why. I think I miss something on array theory.

"Someone" adds at the end of my arrays some sort of char characters such as ?^)(&%. For example if I have an array of lenght 5 with "hello", so it's full, sometimes it prints hello?()/&%%. I can undesrtand it can occur if it's of 10 elements and i use only 5, so maybe the other 5 elements get some random values, but if it's full, where the hell gets those strange values?

I partially solve it by manaully adding at the end the character '\0'.

For example this problem occurs, sometimes, when I try to fill an array from another array (i read a line form a test file with fgets, then I have to extract single words):

```
...
for(x=0;fgets(c,500,fileb);x++) { // read old local file        
int l=strlen(c);
    i=0;
    for (k=0;k<(l-34);k++) {
        if(c[k+33]!='\n') {
            userDatabaseLocalPath[k]=c[k+33];
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You miss the part where strings **must** end with the character `0`.

Comment: Without seeing some sample code, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings in C are terminated by a character with the value 0, often referred to as a character literal, i.e. `'\0'`.

A character array of size 5 can not hold the string `hello`, since the terminator doesn't fit. Functions expecting a terminator will be confused.

To declare an array holding a string, the best syntax to use is:

```
char greeting[] = "hello";
```

This way, you don't need to specify the length (count the characters), since the compiler does that for you. And you also don't need to include the terminator, it's added automatically so the above will create this, in memory:

```
          +-+-+-+-+-+--+
greeting: |h|e|l|l|o|\0|
          +-+-+-+-+-+--+
```

You say that you have problems "filling an array from another longer array", this sounds like an operation most referred to as *string copying*. Since strings are just arrays with terminators, you can't blindly copy a longer string over a shorter, unless you know that there is extra space.

Given the above, this code would invoke undefined behavior:

```
strcpy(greeting, "hi there!");
```

since the string being copied into the `greeting` array is longer than what the array has space for.

This is typically avoided by using "known to be large enough" buffers, or adding checks that manually keep track of the space used. There is a function called `strncpy()` which sort of does this, but I would not recommend using it since its exact semantics are fairly odd.

Comment: Ok, so at least my array dimension should be needed+1, right? And the termination character '\0' is added automatically or I have to add it?

This problem occurs in particular when I have to fill an array from another longer array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
For example I have an array long enough, and I have to copy its elements from X to Y in a new array. My array contains hash and path of a file, I read it from a txt with fgets. I want to save hash and path in 2 different array. It's possible without doing it elements by elements? This should be the final result:

array="b1663252583060c5bb25817169686c39 /Users/poi/ppp.jpg"
array1"b1663252583060c5bb25817169686c39"
array2"/Users/poi/ppp.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the issue of boundary limit for the array.. if the array is of size 5 , then its not necessary that the sixth location which will be `\0` be safe.. As it is not memory reserved/assigned for your array.. If after sometime some other application accesses this memory and writes to it. you will lose the `\0` resulting in the string `helloI accessed this space` being read. which is what you are getting.